# Шляпный переполох

Tags: дефект, поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Это только у меня шляпы то появляются, то исчезают?

По три раза одной и той же шляпой награждают. Наградят - снимут, наградят - снимут :)

Вот и сейчас - у меня шляпа, которой нет в списке моих шляп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас их забрали, потому что воровать плохо. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDcaO.jpg

Comment: @Danis Это еще что такое?... https://ibb.co/rHL3Pdc

Comment: вашу забрали, а украденная осталась :)

Comment: Да, у меня тоже то 9, то 7…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [этом посте на Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/383809) есть детали о секретных шляпах, подтвержденные и неподтвержденные догадки о том, каковы критерии их получения.

Для **наушников** и **балалайки** есть следующее сообщение:

> There was a bug in the hat trigger that resulted in the hat being awarded to users who shouldn't have received it. All hats awarded prior to 2020-12-17 21:04 (UTC) have been revoked, and been re-awarded only to users who actually qualified for it.

что можно суммировать как:

> В активации этой шляпы был баг, из-за которого шляпы были выданы пользователям, которые не должны были их получить. Все шляпы этого типа выданные до 21:04 (UTC) 17 декабря были отозваны и будут перевыданы пользователям, которые действительно их заслужат.

Похожая ситуация и с **флагом-вексилолога**:

> There was a bug in the hat trigger that resulted in the hat being awarded to users who shouldn't have received it. All hats awarded prior to 2020-12-16 13:18 (UTC) have been revoked, and been re-awarded only to users who actually qualified for it.

где разница лишь в дате отзыва шляп.

Никто из списка эти шляпы не убирал и изображения не менял. Это не имеет ничего общего с шапкой-ушанкой и прошлым годом.

NB: Как правильно [заметил Alexandr_TT](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11235/337980), шляпы, которые уже на аватаре, там и останутся, даже если их отзовут. Разумеется, поменять и вернуть обратно на отозванную балалайку не получится.

Будем считать, что у нас теперь начинается второй поход за балалайкой, и это здорово!

Comment: справедливости ради, замечу, что я начал получать шляпы, позже указанного вами срока. Балалайка, была получена, одной из последних шляп. Так что вызывает опять же сомнения, процитированный вами пост Может я ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT эти данные были подтверждены в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020) сотрудниками SE, т.е. я сильно сомневаюсь в том что это не так. Кроме того, возможно разница во времени (UTC).

Comment: Например: [конкретное сообщение от Catija по балалайке](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56468782#56468782)

Comment: если дело во времени (UTC), то как объяснить факт исчезновения балалайки, полученной после других шляп. Тогда должны были исчезнуть полученные ранее шляпы

Comment: @Alexandr_TT если важны уже такие детали, то тут я советую идти в [чат комнату по шляпам](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117306/winter-bash-2020) и спрашивать. Общая ситуация точно обусловлена багами в триггерах, которые были исправлены, и о которых официально заявляли сотрудники за это отвечающие :)

Comment: думаю всё проще произошло. Сняли балалайку и другие шляпы с ошибками, с тех кто раньше получил и с тех кто позже получил, особо не разбираясь, так же проще.. И ещё не факт, что можно повторно получить, где нибудь в базе осталась отметка, что человек уже получал данную шляпу и второй раз, естесственно не положено получать.

Comment: Вижу балалайки начали возвращаться

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что те шляпы, которые человек успел добавить к аватарке, до удаления шляпы из списка остались на аватарке. Для примера у [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor) балалайка осталась на аватарке, у  [@HamSter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212421/hamster) те же наушники, как у вас остались на аватарке.
Конечно такая тенденция с удалением шляп по непонятным причинам, настораживает и дискриминирует саму идею шляп, как какое-то праздничное мероприятие, приносящее к тому же пользу в повышенной активности пользователей SO.

Если вслед за удалением балалайки последуют удаления матрешки, самовара из списка шляп, то выводы напрашиваются сами собой.
Вспомните прошлогодние разборки насчет шапки-ушанки со звёздочкой.